# Postponed sieve algorithm with start logic

Tags: algorithms, primes

Based on [the answer by Will Ness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2211990/how-to-implement-an-efficient-infinite-generator-of-prime-numbers-in-python/10733621), I've been using a JavaScript adaptation for the postponed sieve algorithm:

```js
function * primes() {
    yield 2;
    yield 3;
    yield 5;
    yield 7;
    const sieve = new Map();
    const ps = primes();
    ps.next() && ps.next();
    for (let p = 3, i = 9; true; i += 2) {
        let s = sieve.get(i);
        if (s !== undefined) {
            sieve.delete(i);
        } else if (i < p * p) {
            yield i;
            continue;
        } else {
            s = 2 * p;
            p = ps.next().value;
        }
        let k = i + s;
        while (sieve.has(k)) k += s;
        sieve.set(k, s);
    }
}
```

But now that I need to add `start` point to it, I am struggling to wrap my head around it, for the logic here isn't straightforward.

When `start` is a prime, I need it to be the first value. And when `start` is not a prime, I need the sequence to start with the first prime after `start`.

Will Ness suggested in one of the comments:

> You would have to come up with the valid sieve dictionary for the start point. It's easy to get the needed primes - just run this algo up to `sqrt(start)`, then you need to find each core prime's multiple just above (or is it just below?) the start, while minding the duplicates.

Wielding this into reality however is not that simple (or at least for me) :|

Can anybody help with updating this algorithm for such `*primes(start)` implementation (preferably in JavaScript as above)?

```js
function * primes(start) {

  // how to amend it to support 'start' logic???

}
```

Comment: Programming is off-topic here.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus This section of StackExchange is for algorithms, which is exactly what it is. I followed [the guidelines](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-sites-do-i-post-on) here. Where else would I ask such a question?

Comment: Questions specific to JavaScript are off-topic here.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Where would it be not off-topic then?

Comment: You can try [so]. Another option is to rewrite the question so that it's not specific to JavaScript, and in particular, doesn't require knowledge of JavaScript.

Comment: Use of the `Map` here is essential to the algorithm, so I cannot easily rewrite it in something else. I would think that JavaScript is considered ubiquitous enough for a generic algorithm question.

Comment: Ok, [I have re-published the question on regular StackExchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69336435/postponed-sieve-algorithm-with-start-logic). Probably will close this one now.